# PHP Session handling class

Tags: php, object-oriented, session

I've written a custom PHP session class for handling sessions across the web app. Please review the code and point out mistakes and suggest better handling techniques.

```
require_once('config.php');

class Sessions {

protected $sessionID;

public function __construct(){
    if( !isset($_SESSION) ){
        $this->init_session();
    }
    //session_start();
    //$this->sessionID = session_id();
}

public function init_session(){
    session_start();
}

public function set_session_id(){
    //$this->start_session();
    $this->sessionID = session_id();
}

public function get_session_id(){
    return $this->sessionID;
}

public function session_exist( $session_name ){
    if( isset($_SESSION[$session_name]) ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function create_session( $session_name , $is_array = false ){
    if( !isset($_SESSION[$session_name])  ){
        if( $is_array == true ){
            $_SESSION[$session_name] = array();
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION[$session_name] = '';
        }
    }
}

public function insert_value( $session_name , array $data ){
    if( is_array($_SESSION[$session_name]) ){
        array_push( $_SESSION[$session_name], $data );
    }
}

public function display_session( $session_name ){
    echo '<pre>';print_r($_SESSION[$session_name]);echo '</pre>';
}

public function remove_session( $session_name = '' ){
    if( !empty($session_name) ){
        unset( $_SESSION[$session_name] );
    }
    else{
        unset($_SESSION);
        //session_unset();
        //session_destroy();
    }
}

public function get_session_data( $session_name ){
    return $_SESSION[$session_name];
}

public function set_session_data( $session_name , $data ){
    $_SESSION[$session_name] = $data;
}

}
```

Comment: Why is there so much core-functionality (at least by name) commented out?

Comment: I don't understand your comment brother. Can you please explain?

Comment: first off. I am not your brother. It's not really helpful and not winning you points with me. Secondly the core use of a session is starting it, right? why is `$this->start_session()` `session_start()` and the like commented out then??

Comment: Oh right, actually I intended to use `init_session()` for starting session. And I've called it in the constructor so that the session starts automatically when the object is created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Commented out Code**

You should remove code that is commented out. If you think that you might need it in the future, think about using version control.

**`set_session_id()`**

This is only called in your commented out code. Does the user have to call it manually? If they don't, `get_session_id()` will return a wrong result. Maybe rewrite it like this (you don't seem to be using the field `$sessionID`, so you might as well get rid of it):

```
public function get_session_id(){
    return session_id();
}
```

**if-else and `session_exist`**

If you have code like this:

```
if( isset($_SESSION[$session_name]) ){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

you can rewrite it like this:

```
return isset($_SESSION[$session_name]);
```

Also, when you define a function like this, then use it. Instead of

```
if( !isset($_SESSION[$session_name])  ){
```

write

```
if(!session_exist($session_name]) ){
```

**XSS**

Using [Session for XSS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/altering-a-session-variable-in-php-via-xss) might be a possibility, depending on how your code is used. So in `display_session` I would clean the session with `htmlentities` to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: hey Tim thank you for pointing that our bro. I've fixed the code as per your suggestions. Can you suggest what more functions should I add in this class? Or what important functions am i missing.

Comment: maybe `remove_value`? You could also look at what other people have in their session classes. codeigniter for example has [`Flashdata`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). But I think that you can just leave it as it is and add functionality as it is needed.

Comment: `This is only called in your commented out code. Does the user have to call it manually?`
No I've called `init_session()` in the constructor dude.

Comment: Yes, but `init_session()` doesn't set `$this->sessionID = session_id();`. `sessionID` isn't set anywhere, and thus `get_session_id()` will always return null.

Comment: What do you think about session expiry functions?

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, it looks like a mess to me and it's difficult to read. Your naming convention is also off. They don't appear to do what you (or any other programmer) would think it does by looking at the name of your methods (not to mention your variables too).

- Method `session_exist()` is not what it seems. It's not checking if a session exist, but it's rather checking if a session parameter exist. I would rename that to `parameterExist()`.
- Method `create_session()` does *not* create sessions. It sets session parameters. I would call it `setParameter()` instead.
- Method `insert_value()`, what does it even do? :|

  So you're taking in a session name (?) and an array of data. Then you're checking if the session name is an array? And if it is you push the data array that's passed in to it? Is there any difference beween `create_session()` and `insert_value()`? I'm confused.
- Why does your class contain a `sessionID` property?

  It looks like your using it to eh, differentiate between session objects? If that's the case the object itself can serve for that. Unless you have some other intentions for it I would just get rid of it and it's setter and getter.

I could go on and on, but this should be enough to let you realize other obvious problems that are an issue with your code.

Comment: `session_exist()` Originally I wrote this method with optional argument. Without the argument it would check that if session has been originated or not. I just forgot to change the name after having made the argument compulsory.

`create_session()` Yes you are right about it, sir.

`insert_value()` I'm using this method for inserting a new value in session array by using array push.

`create_session()` just creates a new index in session array, on the other hand `insert_value()` inserts new value at a specified index of session array.

`sessionID` I made for future use, but never used it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to make naming suggestion to your class. Since the class is called Sessions, the object will likely be called $session or similar. Thus, make the word session in the method names superfluous. Further, since we're dealing with objects and data all the time in programming, I try to be very selective when to include them, as they often time aren't needed.

Apply these changes would result in the following:

```
 $session->get_session_data()
```

Would be become:

```
$session->get_session();
```

Also,

```
$session->session_init();
```

would become:

```
$session->init();
```