# Shopping Cart Handler Class

Tags: php, object-oriented, security, e-commerce

I've written an eCommerce shopping cart handler class in PHP. Please review the code and inform me of any errors and/or badly written code and/or badly handled logics. Please also inform me of any missing functionality or security loopholes.

```
class Cart extends Sessions{

protected $cartProducts = array();
protected $dbLink;
protected $cartName;

public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct(); // to run the constructor of parent
    $this->cartName = 'cart';
    try{
        $this->dbLink = new db;
    }
    catch( Exception $e ){
        echo $e->getMessage() , '\n';
    }
}

public function __destruct(){
    $this->dbLink = FALSE;
}

public function cart_exist(){
    return $this->session_exist($this->cartName);
}

public function create_cart(){
    $this->create_session($this->cartName, true);
    $this->cartProducts = &$_SESSION[$this->cartName];
}

public function add_product( $data ){
    if( !$this->cart_exist() ){
        $this->create_cart();
    }
    $this->insert_value($this->cartName, $data );
}

public function display_cart(){
    $this->display_session($this->cartName);
}

public function del_from_cart( $index ){
    unset($_SESSION[$this->cartName][$index]);
}

public function update_cart_item( $index , array $data ){
    if( array_key_exists( $index , $_SESSION[$this->cartName]) ){
        $arr = &$_SESSION[$this->cartName][$index];
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ){
            $arr[$key] = $data[$key];
        }
    }
}

public function remove_cart(){
    $this->remove_session($this->cartName);
}

}
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to link to the `Sessions` class. For anyone interested, the code is [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61066/php-session-handling-class).

Comment: This is the session class, from which this cart class has been inherited.
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61066/php-session-handling-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things:

- Comments like this one:

  ```
      parent::__construct(); // to run the constructor of parent
  ```

  provide no real value; they just repeat what the code does.  Prefer reserving comments
  for tricky bits of code that aren't self-explanatory.
- You never use `$dbLink`; get rid of it. If subclasses need a database, let *them*
  create one.
- `__destruct` is largely unnecessary here.  You gain nothing from detaching references at
  this point; PHP will already release them once your destructor returns.  And if you
  followed the previous point, the only thing you're releasing no longer exists anyway.
- All your variables are `protected`, which implies that you are planning for subclasses to
  exist.  I'm not sure specializing a cart even makes much sense, though.

  Unless you already *have* subclasses, and those subclasses *need* basically
  unrestricted access to those properties, you should make them `private`.
  (And even if you do, you might want to reexamine whether inheritance is the proper
  relationship.)
- You have a public constructor *and* a "`create_cart`" function?  That's going to confuse
  people.  (You already created a `Cart` when you said `new Cart`.)  It looks like what you
  need here is a name that more clearly describes what the function does.
- I'm not a big fan of instance method names that include the containing class's name.
  It feels like a symptom (or maybe a cause) of drifting away from OO concepts and back
  to proceduralism.

  This is just personal preference; take it as you will.  But IMO, if you have a `Cart`,
  then from now until it dies, it will always be a `Cart`.  You don't have to keep
  reminding it of that.  :)
- I see that `$cartProducts` is a reference to an array in `$_SESSION`.  At that
  point, both names refer to the exact same value.  Any change you make to
  `$this->cartProducts` also happens to `$_SESSION[$this->cartName]`, and vice versa.

  Which makes me wonder: Why do so many methods mess with
  `$_SESSION[$this->cartName]` rather than with `$this->cartProducts`?
- Variable names like `$data` aren't very descriptive.  You know a product is being
  added; most carts would include a quantity as well.  But i don't know for sure what
  `$data` looks like, for two big reasons.  One is the name.  The other...?
- **You let the caller stuff whatever garbage it wants to in your cart.**

  A cart keeps track of *items* (or *products*), and typically quantities as well,
  and usually has a way to get a total price.  This cart is basically a list of blobs,
  and can't currently do any of that stuff easily, because it doesn't exert any type of
  ownership.

  The list of items is *your* domain, not the caller's.  Unless this is intended to be a
  generic list of "whatever", *you* decide the structure of what goes into it -- and in
  return, you get the ability to do stuff over and above what a stock list can do.
  Otherwise, the caller is actually worse off using your cart than mucking around with
  the `$_SESSION['cart']` array directly.  (At least when they're using `$_SESSION`,
  they *know* they're farting around with global state.  Your class hides that fact behind
  what *looks* like a per-instance interface.)

  You don't necessarily need to say "everything you insert must be an instance of this
  particular class".  You could conceivably let the caller decide that much.  But you can
  -- and probably should -- require that they exhibit certain behaviors (like having a
  `get_price()` method).  These requirements should be *documented*.  And if you're
  tracking quantities, then do so explicitly -- consider making `$quantity` a discrete
  parameter to the `add_product` method.

  Once you have decided how an item must behave, then you can do stuff that a typical
  cart does out of the box.  If you decide items must have a price, for example, then
  now you can add a way to get the total price of all items.   That in itself is part
  of the bare minimum functionality i expect of *any* shopping cart class.  If it doesn't
  have that, it's just another list.  :P

But the really big thing i'm seeing here is the relationship between carts and sessions.  A `Cart` might *have* a session, or *use* a session.  But it is really a different thing.  Inheriting from `Sessions` seems to me incorrect, unless the parent class is badly named.

It feels to me, though, like you have the relationship the wrong way around.  **A Cart is obviously *part* of a session**, as evidenced by your bunch of functions to manage subsets of session data.

And **PHP lets you put objects in a session.**

*The cart itself* could be session data, at which point `$session->gimme('some cart name')`
can return a whole `Cart` object, and all this session-management stuff becomes obsolete.

In order to make it work:

- The class needs to be loaded, or autoloadable, before `session_start()`.
- The class must be serializable...which requires that anything you need to
  persist must also be serializable, and/or that anything that's not serializable
  not be included in the list of properties to store.
  That's usually not a big deal; the only things PHP can't serialize are resources and
  quasi-resources like your `$dbLink`.
  (One of a number of reasons `$dbLink` probably isn't worth keeping.  But even if you
  do, you can add a `__wakeup()` function to reinitialize it.)

The main thing to keep in mind is that if you only want the item info serialized, or you have unserializable fields (like `$dbLink`), you should provide a `__sleep` method that tells PHP which properties to serialize.  You'll probably also want a `__wakeup()` method to reinitialize those items that you didn't serialize.

With all that taken care of...what's left?

```
class Cart {
    private $items = [];

    public function add_product($product, $quantity) {
        $this->items[] = ['product' => $item, 'quantity' => $quantity];
    }

    public function delete_product_at($index) {
        unset($this->items[$index]);
    }

    public function update_product_at($index, $product, $quantity) {
        if (isset($this->items[$index])) {
            $this->items[$index] = ['product' => $product, 'quantity' => $quantity];
        }
    }

    public function get_total() {
        return array_reduce($this->items, function($sum, $item) {
            return $sum + $item['product']->get_price() * $item['quantity'];
        }, 0);
    }



    # don't really need __sleep or __wakeup, since $dbLink is gone.  But it might be
    # helpful to illustrate their use.
    private $some_value;

    public function __sleep() {
        # in `__sleep`, you return a list of properties you want saved
        return ['items'];
    }

    public function __wakeup() {
        # since $some_value wasn't serialized, it doesn't have a value.
        # before you use it again, set it to something sensible.

        $this->some_value = 42;
    }
}
```

The main missing piece left at this point is your `display_cart` function.  Not sure what it does...but frankly, if its name is accurate, it shouldn't be here.  :P

This is a *model* class, or a *business object* if you don't care about MVC and such.  It's responsible for managing the data, and for representing it in a way that the UI can do something with it. But most schools of thought on software architecture would say this class shouldn't be involved in the actual presentation/rendering.  That's the job of the code that manages the UI.

If you want to be able to list the cart's contents, two simple ways would be to have a function that returns `$this->items`, or implement the `IteratorAggregate` interface and have a `getIterator()` function return an iterator over `$this->items`.

Comment: Woah thank you for such explanatory feedback dude. It will take me some time to read, understand and implement your points. I'll post back for further questions etc soon :)

Comment: I've implemented most of your points. Now about the `$data` in `add_product()` method. It is actually an array (which i forgot to mention that time). It contains `product_id`, `quantity`.

Comment: yes you are right `display_cart()` doesn't belong here.

Comment: @OMI: You need a more descriptive name than `$data`.  :)  But if the caller is building cart items itself, even accessing them by index...?  Sounds like you could do all that with a plain old array.  Classes shouldn't exist for their own sake -- they should exist to abstract away some complexity of the app.  Key word being *away*; they should take that complexity upon themselves, so the caller doesn't have to worry itself anymore and ends up simpler and better off using the class than trying to DIY it.  Step back and ask `Cart` to justify its existence.  What does it abstract away?

Comment: I agree with you there it is not abstracting any complexity which it really should I think.

Comment: @OMI: Well, to the caller, all that really matters is *what products*, and *how many of each*, right?  So try to hide the rest. Don't even hint at indexes, arrays, etc -- in the item-management API, all that exists are products and quantities. (For instance, instead of an index, use the product/ID as your lookup key.) Then the caller basically *can't* worry about that stuff.

Comment: @OMI: Even better, if you have the "add" and "remove" methods update the quantity of an existing item whenever possible (rather than adding or deleting an entry each time), then a `Cart` is basically an abstraction for "a set of product counts".  I'd still like to see a way to get the total price, but that'd be out of scope unless/until you accept whole products rather than just IDs.

Comment: I'm coming to understand your point now. I'm gonna implement these points and will show you :)

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of points:

- Your `Cart` class violates the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

  You are extending from your session handler class, which you shouldn't because it  shouldn't be the cart's responsibility to also handle session management. Your class is having **3** different responsibilities. I would instead separate those two classes and inject `Sessions` as a dependency into `Cart`.
- You have hard-coded the cart name (`$this->cartName = 'cart';`). Now what if you would want to change the name of the cart? You would have to modify the class to change it, and then still **every** cart would have the same name. I suggest you make it dynamic by injecting it (into the constructor) so you can define this when instantiating the class.  *(see dependency injection at the bottom of this answer)*
- `display_cart()` doesn't belong there, the 3rd responsibility of this class.

  After you've separated the classes they should both have one responsibility. But that would still not be the case because this method prints a HTML formatted string. I would rather rename it to something like `getProductsData()` which would probably have to **return** an array with all the products the cart contains. And then you can move the responsibility to print the data in a HTML format to somewhere else.
- Your class dependency `dbLink` is redundant, because you aren't using it anywhere. Even if you would use it, I would give the responsibility of persisting anything to a new class. With that being said, the `__destruct()` method can be deleted.
- I see you have `$this->cartProducts = &$_SESSION[$this->cartName];`. Is there any reason why you are assigning the reference of the superglobal to this class property? I fail to see why you would do that, and you aren't using it anywhere. You might as well just return `$_SESSION[$this->cartName];`.

  Secondly, I'm assuming `$cartProducts` is supposed to keep track of the products the cart contains, but I don't see your `add_product()` method adding anything to it. :/

There are a lot of things wrong with this class, I hope this is of any help.

**Dependency Injection**

```
public function __construct($name, Sessions $sessions)
{
    $this->cartName = $name;
    $this->sessions = $sessions;
}
```

Comment: I like the way you used dependency injection. To be honest, initially I went this way, initiating `session` class and storing its reference in local variable. But I don't remember now why I erased this and chose the other way around i.e. `inheriting` from `session` class directly. I will look into your feedback in detail and post back for `extended` help ;)
P.S. Thanks for your support. You guys are awesome!